# Text overlaying select box in Firefox

Tags: html, select

On my [**site**](http://news.depfinder.com/), I have a select box (instruments) that, when opened, overlays the image and text in the top half of the page.

The problem, as you will see if you are browsing in Firefox, is that the text/image makes it impossible to click a select option that sits on top of it.

This has me stumped - how might I fix it so that the text/image doesn't interfere with the select box?

Comment: Please avoid linking to external sites — they are susceptible to link rot and makes the question less relevant and useful to future users. Consider porting your issue over to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `z-index` from `.intro-text`

```
.intro-text {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*z-index: 1000;*/;
}
```

Comment: I changed your sentence to make sense and fixed the code indentation :-) You can as well click on the "edited x mins ago" to see a diff.

Comment: Yeah just kidding. :)